# How to fix zits and blobs caused by Cura?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, slicing, creality-cr-10, octoprint, surface

I am using a Creality CR-10S Pro, and lately, I've been having problems with zits and blobs on my surface whenever I do an aesthetic print that has more curves and turns than a functional print would have. I think it started when I started using OctoPrint. I'm pretty sure the slicer is causing it, but I don't know exactly what setting. This are the results I'm getting with PLA at 60 mm/s and 10 % infill:

[image: Print results with 10 % infill]

After this, I just changed the infill to 0 % and it fixed it, but only in the first few layers. I thought I had solved the problem, but after a particular layer, it started again (less than before, but still). These are the results:

[image: Print results with 0 % infill]

This only makes it even more mind-boggling to me. What setting is causing this? I tried changing the maximum resolution and maximum deviation but returned to the first results.

Comment: Looks overextruded. Does it appear in vase mode as well?

Comment: @towe That was the first thing that came to me -- one or both of overextrusion or overheating the nozzle.

Comment: Like I said, the problem started with octoprint. It's not the profile. I just printed the same gcode via sdcard instead of octoprint and it came out perfectly. cura is therefore ruled out too. it's a processor/communication issue.

Comment: If you installed on a lower end Raspberry Pi, you could run into problems the the Pi cannot keep up with the printer, what Raspberry Pi did you use?